# Java Script not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following script where I calculate a price based on user input radio buttons and output it into a section of html.  The script is not working in internet explorer properly.

```
var newprice = "";        

function CalcPrice(){
    // I take the input from the radio buttons here 
    var goals = $("#menu input[type='radio']:checked").val();

    if (goals=="Weight Loss"){
        newprice="45";
    } else {
        newprice="55";
    }

    $('.pricetotal').html("$"+newprice.toFixed(2));
}
```

HTML

```
<form class= "meal-table" id="meal-radio" onsubmit="return false">
          <fieldset id="menu">
         <input type="radio" id="radio01" name="menu" value="Weight Loss" />
         <input type="radio" id="radio02" name="menu" value= "Performance"/>
          </fieldset>
    <div>
      <div class="meal-plan-btn">
        <button id="mealbtn" onclick="CalcPrice()">Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

// this is where the price will be injected

```
          <div class="pricebox" id="priceboxmobile">
            <div class="pricetotal" >
              <span ></span>
            </div></div>
```

Comment: can you show me the full code , i think you are using jQuery right ?

Comment: `The script is not working in internet explorer properly` .. two questions, is it working in real browsers? (Chrum, Firfox, Edge) ... second, in what way isn't it working in internet explorer? not at all, a bit but has some errors in the console? the devil is in the details

Comment: @billynoah - that's funny, but ultimately unhelpful :p

Comment: @JaromandaX  Yes it is working in firefox and chrome I believe safari as well, however have a hard time testing safari without a mac.

Comment: safari is the new IE anyway :p - so, in what way doesn't it work in IE? describe the problem if you want help with the problem

Comment: @JaromandaX  Trying to test it now, but cant seem to figure out if it is a problem with getting the data from the radio buttons or if the problem is how i am trying to set the price at the end of the script.

Comment: so, it's not working at all? is the page **hosted** (locally or otherwise) in a http server, or are you using `file:///` - if the latter, IE restricts running javascript - there should be a warning about this, if not, there's possibly a setting somewhere

Comment: It is hosted in a http server

Comment: why do you have an `else` statement that does nothing?

Comment: @Pang than can you please let me know how my code is not meeting those requirements?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you gave us the error message or, if there is none, told us what is improper about the result and the version of IE and the version of jQuery you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this line

$('.pricetotal').html("$"+newprice.toFixed(2));
To:

$('.pricetotal').empty().html("$"+newprice.toFixed(2));